# What are Builds steps of maui app in teamcity?

Tags: .net-core, deployment, teamcity, maui, cicd

I am trying to deploy an maui app in teamcity. I did connect teamcity with gitlab, and teamcity created two build steps automatically, "NuGet installer" and ".Net". But I really don't have any idea about other build steps to add manually, I couldn't find any docs or video about building maui app in teamcity. I hope someone can help me or provide me any source of information that could help me.

Comment: I think your question lacks a bit of details of what you're not understanding/finding unclear from Maui guidance about publishing an app and a bit of context about what you're trying to achieve (public publishing or publishing to an internal repo for tests). I'm not able to answer that, but that's what I'd like to know to narrow the search/approach an answer on another subject.